# WebConfig doesn't return measurementId

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-analytics

I am trying to enable firebase analytics in my existing firebase project. The project is  a static React website that only uses Firebase hosting.

Following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web) get start tutorial, I am getting the following **error** in my console:

> Ignored "config" command. Invalid arguments found

Searching how to solve this problem, I found [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4063#issuecomment-726429691) comment and checked that my webConfig get request is not returning the measurementId. **However I couldn't find any info about how to correct it.**

```js
//firebase.js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics} from "firebase/analytics";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "{ApiKey}",
  authDomain: "{projectId}.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "{projectId}",
  storageBucket: "{projectId}.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "{messagingSenderId}",
  appId: "{appId}",
  measurementId: "{measurementId}",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

WebConfig call (Http 200, Get):

response:

```json
{
  "projectId": "{projectId}",
  "appId": "{appId}",
  "storageBucket": "{projectId}.appspot.com",
  "authDomain": "{projectId}.firebaseapp.com",
  "messagingSenderId":  "{messagingSenderId}"
}
```

Is there any config that I am missing? what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Use a new firebase web app.

---

I ran into the same problem, I suspect it's because I made a Firebase web app before enabling analytics, so the app might have been stuck at some weird state.

To fix it I made sure Analytics is enabled, tos accepted etc.. then created a new firebase web app and connected that to my app.

Answer (score 0):

There could be something wrong with the stream for your web app that’s why the measurementId is not being configured. You could try to unlink and [relink](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en#linkga) to your Google Analytics integration which usually resolves any broken integration. Make sure that the currently linked GA property is the one you’re going to use for relinking to avoid losing your data.